# FFmpeg in a bash script ( quotes )

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script that open a text file with some ffmpeg commands. ( about 10 command generated from an other project ) Each command are working when i copy paste than into the terminal manually, but when the script run, simple commands work but I am stuck on a " No such filter : ..." error.

Here is my command : `-i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -i 6.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1][2:0][2:1][3:0][3:1][4:0][4:1][5:0][5:1]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -aspect 16:9 -s 1280x720 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libmp3lame -y track_0.mp4`

I think all the problem is in the " ' " i try to escape them with " \' " but ffmpeg is telling me `No such filter: '''`

Here is my script assuming that the variable ARGS is set dynamically ( for the example I have set it manually ) :

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGS="-i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -i 6.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1][2:0][2:1][3:0][3:1][4:0][4:1][5:0][5:1]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -aspect 16:9 -s 1280x720 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libmp3lame -y track_0.mp4"
ffmpeg ${ARGS}
```

EDIT 1:

Well I forgot to precise that my text file is like that :

```
-loop 1 -f image2 -c:v png -i FILE_0.data -i sample.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -t 20 -s 1280x720 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libmp3lame  -pix_fmt yuv420p -y 4.mp4
-loop 1 -f image2 -c:v png -i black.png -i sample.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -t 14 -s 1280x720 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libmp3lame  -pix_fmt yuv420p -y 5.mp4
-loop 1 -f image2 -c:v png -i FILE_1.data -i sample.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -t 20 -s 1280x720 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libmp3lame  -pix_fmt yuv420p -y 6.mp4
-i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -i 6.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1][2:0][2:1][3:0][3:1][4:0][4:1][5:0][5:1]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -aspect 16:9 -s 1280x720 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libmp3lame -y track_0.mp4
```

And in this file I read each line and I pass the line to ffmpeg to process what i want

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's [have a look](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
$ shellcheck yourscript
ARGS="-i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -i 6.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1][2:0][2:1][3:0][3:1][4:0][4:1][5:0][5:1]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -aspect 16:9 -s 1280x720 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libmp3lame -y track_0.mp4"
      ^-- SC2089: Quotes/backslashes will be treated literally. Use an array.

In yourscript line 3:
ffmpeg ${ARGS}
       ^-- SC2090: Quotes/backslashes in this variable will not be respected.
```

As suggested, let's [use an array](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2089):

```
#!/bin/bash
args=(
  -i "1.mp4"
  -i "2.mp4" ... 
  -filter_complex '[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1][2:0][2:1][3:0][3:1][4:0][4:1][5:0][5:1]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v] [a]' 
  -map '[v]' 
  -map '[a]' 
  -aspect 16:9
  ....
)
ffmpeg "${args[@]}"
```

Obviously this works equally well if you build the array dynamically, e.g. with

```
args=()
for f in 1.mp4 2.mp4
do
  args+=(-i "$f")
done
...
```

To explain why this works, here's what you expected would happen:

1. Bash sees `ffmpeg $ARGS`
2. Bash substitutes the variable, giving `ffmpeg -i 'my arg'`
3. Bash interprets the new command, giving the argument list

   `ffmpeg`, `-i`, `my arg`
4. Bash runs `ffmpeg` with these two arguments

This is what actually happens:

1. Bash sees `ffmpeg $ARGS`
2. Bash interprets it and splits it into the arguments

   `ffmpeg` `$ARGS`
3. Bash sees that one of the arguments is an unquoted variable, so it [splits the value of the variable on spaces](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and puts each word into a separate argument:

   `ffmpeg`, `-i`, `'my`, `file'`
4. Bash runs ffmpeg with these **three** arguments, which now contain garbage single quotes.

Comment: I forgot one thing look my first post and you will understand

Comment: @GuillaumeVillena What thing?

Comment: As I said, I read a text file with all the args that I need to pass to ffmpeg, and I just post an example of my file.

Comment: @GuillaumeVillena That's a fragile and insecure way to do it. If you really, seriously want to do it anyways, you can use `eval "ffmpeg $ARGS"`.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what you said because I misread your very good explanation ( sorry I am french and I have some difficulties with english )